# which pythonwin should I download for python 2.7 32bit installed on Intel 64 bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, intel, windows64

I am trying to download PythonWin windows extension for python.

From this official page http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

There are many options but as you see:

1. There are python for `AMD` processor but I have `Intel` processor
2. There are no `Intel` specific version.

When I type `Python` on my cmd, I got this:

> Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
>   32

Note please that I installed python 2.7 32 bit on Intel Windows 64bit

thanks

Comment: Personally I use the ActiveState distro which comes with pywin32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe
```

- `pywin32-219` means version 219 of pywin32.
- `win32` means 32 bit (as opposed to `amd64` which means 64 bit).
- `py2.7` means Python 2.7.